# When component instance created

Tags: reactjs, components

I have sub component inside another. All of them creates (runs constructor) at the begining. But when i working inside component (click button) my inner component creates again (runs constructor).
**In which cases react recreate element?**

Example:

```
class TestAppComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(params) {
    super(params);
    console.log("TestAppComponent created");

    this.TestInnerComponent1=<TestInnerComponent message="I am 1" />
    this.TestInnerComponent2=<TestInnerComponent message="I am 2" />

    this.order=true;
  }
  onClickedFire(){
    this.order=!this.order;
    this.setState({asd:"asd"});
  }
  RenderComponents(){
    if(this.order){
      return(<div>
        <div>
          {this.TestInnerComponent1}
          {this.TestInnerComponent2}
        </div>
      </div>);
    }
    return(<div>
      {this.TestInnerComponent2}
      {this.TestInnerComponent1}
    </div>);
  }
  render(){
    console.log("TestAppComponent render");
    return(<div>
      {this.RenderComponents()}
      <button onClick={this.onClickedFire.bind(this)} >Fire!!!</button>
    </div>);
  }
}
class TestInnerComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(params) {
    super(params);
    console.log("TestInnerComponent created");
  }
  render(){
    console.log("TestInnerComponent render");
    return(<div>
      {this.props.message}
    </div>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share some code of your component, will help the community to answer better.

Comment: This can occur if you don't provide keys or keys are changing in different renders. You can find what you need here https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html . Or share render method of component where Button is rendered .

Answer (score 0):

`RenderComponents` method return two nested divs in case if `this.order === true`. React knows that top `div` has two children of type `TestInnerComponent`, and now it has only one child of type `div` so React removes old instances and creates all tree under top `div` from scratch. So `TestInnerComponent` instances gets unmounted, created again and mounted in second div. Also it is bad practise to create jsx not in render method.